# Is this lack of speed-up related to the processor or the code?

Tags: cpu

I have written a program that uses MPI, it solves a very large system of equations. I am getting very good "speed-ups" for very large systems. What I mean by this is that if I increase the number of processes then the time it takes to complete halves plus a constant time added to this which I consider to be communication. For instance, on one process it might take 60s then on two it might take 35s (60 + 5) then on 4 it might take 20.5 (17.5+3) etc.

However, when entering systems that are approximately 1 million by 1 million I start to get odd results. When going from 4 cores to 8 cores I get half the time plus 10 seconds "communication". That is, the time it takes to complete the computation goes from ~260 to ~ 140.

This is fine, but then when going from 8 to 16 the time goes from ~140 to ~110, I also get a very similar poor result when going from 16 to 32. That is, ~110 to ~85.

I seem to think it might have something to do with the processor itself, as this behaviour would not just suddenly appear (?).

There are 2 of these processors in the system

https://ark.intel.com/products/120485/Intel-Xeon-Gold-6140-Processor-24_75M-Cache-2_30-GHz

There is about 8000GB of RAM also.

> I would like some explanation as to why this might be happening.

I am happy to provide more information. I know this is a complex issue and  I am not sure what information you need in total.

Comment: How have you written your program? Do separate process instances have to sync with each other or send any data between them? Also do they use anything else besides CPU? Do they consume (more than usual) RAM, do they write on disk (have I/O) or similar?

Comment: Yes there are numerous instances where they sync and one node (master node) sends data across all of the other nodes. However for most of my other experiments (sub 1 mil in size) then communication time as we increase the processor count appears almost constant. Maybe increases a little. But nothing like jumping from 10 to 30+ seconds like in this case.

Comment: What are the actual data quantities being pushed around? You say your "system" is "1 million by 1 million" but that is actually a bit meaningless, how much *data* is having to be synchronised between all these processes as each size you are testing? What programming language are you using? Even Python has MPI, but Python can struggle with massive dynamic datasets... though the same can be said for any language.

Comment: I am using C++. I give the dimension as a product of two even integers, so n = 256 and m = 512 for instance. Suppose I have 4 processes. Then node 0 distributes (512/4)*256^2 "doubles" to each of the processes. The squared is because matrices are being passed around. Does some calculation and then at the end of the calculation MPI_allgather is called.

Comment: If you have two processors and are using MPI, are you taking account of the fact that each processor might have its "own" bank of RAM and data either needs to be present in both banks or the processes on the second CPU may have to read it *through* the first CPU. Is your system using [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) or otherwise hitting such limitations?

Comment: Oh. I did not realise either of those things. Could you provide a reference for the first? Does this phenomenon have a title? I am going to read that NUMA wiki. I might have further questions as to why this limitation only kicks in at "1 million"

Comment: It could well be that it is seen at any size, but as the array is getting wider and taller at the same time you are effectively seeing an exponential increase in data size rather than the linear increase you'd see by just increasing one of the dimensions. Your CPU mentions that it has 3 "UPI links" which is the CPU-to-CPU bus, but I don't immediately see a bandwidth figure for them. It sounds like your "worst" performance loss is when going from 8 to 16 cores, which would point at inter-CPU bandwidth being the limit (unless I'm reading your question wrong).

Comment: Oh, one quick question. If this is the issue would it be overcome by running the code on a "super-computer"? i.e https://ecrc.kaust.edu.sa/Pages/Shaheen-II.aspx ?

Comment: Each processor has 18 cores, so I thought that going from 8 to 16 would not be the issue. But im not going to assume that when I ask for 16 that all 16 are on the same processor, so that could be the case. I am going to have to study this information a bit more. Thanks. If you want to answer this with something similar to above I will accept it.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I thought it came across as a question about hardware limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to diagnose this way, but here are some points :

- Each process uses RAM, so doubling the number of processes means
  doubling the required RAM.
  If the available physical RAM is exhausted, swapping to the disk will slow down
  processing.
- Even in a multi-core computer, some resources are common to all processes.
  These include chiefly RAM and disk, so intensive usage will mean that
  processes will contend on the access to resources and there will be waits.
- If the processes use synchronization methods such as semaphores,
  some wasted time on waits is to be expected, which will increase
  in direct proportion to the number of processes.

Many of these bottlenecks can be seen simply by observing
the behavior of your processes through the Task Manager or Resource Manager,
so you can pinpoint the bottleneck and improve upon it.